# Update only YEAR in a date field in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

I had the following situation: during my data migrations, I realized the year in the date
field was writen with two number only; thus, the 'insert' command included the date in a
wrong way. For example, the year was '1960', but it was writen '60'; so, the 'insert' command
included the year '2060'.

I've been searching for two days on how to update ONLY the year in a date, but no success.
Finally, I've tried this and worked fine to me:

```
UPDATE itens 
SET dtaquisicao = to_date(('1960-' || extract(month from dtaquisicao ) || '-' || extract(day from dtaquisicao )), 'YYYY-mm-dd')
WHERE extract(year from dtaquisicao) = 2060;
```

So, this question is just informative, in case someone needs this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to subtract 100 years.

```
update itens 
   set dtaquisicao = (dtaquisicao - interval '100 years')::date
 where extract(year from dtaquisicao) = 2060;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
UPDATE itens 
SET dtaquisicao = to_date(('1960-' || extract(month from dtaquisicao ) || '-' || extract(day from dtaquisicao )), 'YYYY-mm-dd')
WHERE extract(year from dtaquisicao) = 2060;
```